# When doesn't BeginSend send all the provided bytes?

Tags: c#

socket.EndSend() returns the number of bytes sent. In which instances doesn't socket.BeginSend send all the intended bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If everything goes well, never](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h44aee9.aspx):

> When your application calls BeginSend, the system will use a separate thread to execute the specified callback method, and will block on EndSend until the Socket sends the number of bytes requested or throws an exception.

In case of an unexpected connection loss while sending, an exception will be raised.

Comment: So what is the edge case? When will bytesSent != bytesToSend? I assume there is a reason bytesSent is returned by EndSend...

Comment: @Robin perhaps because it in turn calls `Send()`, which does not guarantee to send all bytes. I do not know.